# Split a string (101500810100015835001000) based on character using excel

Tags: excel

how do i achieve this using excel or any other easier language?

```
original data:
100301010100019743024000 

after formatting:
100,3010,1,01,000,1974,3024,000 

Segment 1 = 3 char
Segment 2 = 4 char
Segment 3 = 1 char
Segment 4 = 2 char
Segment 5 = 3 char
Segment 6 = 4 char
Segment 7 = 4 char
Segment 8 = 3 char
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA has `left()`, `right()` and `mid()` functions for [exactly this purpose](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213646).

A function to do this would look something like:

```
Function FmtStr (MyStr As String) As String
    If Len (MyStr) <> 24 Then
        FmtStr = "?"
    Else
        FmtStr = _
            Mid (MyStr,  1, 3) + "," + _
            Mid (MyStr,  4, 4) + "," + _
            Mid (MyStr,  8, 1) + "," + _
            Mid (MyStr,  9, 2) + "," + _
            Mid (MyStr, 11, 3) + "," + _
            Mid (MyStr, 14, 4) + "," + _
            Mid (MyStr, 18, 4) + "," + _
            Mid (MyStr, 22, 3)
    End If
End Function
```

Calling this with:

```
MsgBox (FmtStr("100301010100019743024000"))
```

gives you a dialog box thus:

[image]

If you just want that in an Excel formula, you can use:

```
=concatenate(mid(a1,1,3), ",", mid(a1,4,4), ",", ... ",", mid(a1,22,3))
```

(assuming the original string was in the `A1` cell of course).

Comment: thank you so so much for the effort put in! But i am sorry to say it is just my first 1hr touching VBA and i am lost in using it. How are the steps like to start of the very basic? I am v sorry.

Comment: @Yeo, as with learning most stuff, a good book on the subject is handy. I've always found the Dummies guides not _too_ bad, or you could check out http://superuser.com/questions/160455/good-books-for-learning-excel-vba

Comment: thank you so so much. the excel formula is so much easier! thank you!